# Transcription of Hindi text to English text

Tags: python

I am working on Hindi speech.

I want to convert Hindi text to English language text in `Python`. I am not interested in translation.

Example of the desired effect: input 'मेरा नाम मोहन है' to output 'mera naam mohan hai'.

Comment: Basically you need to transcript the text instead of translating it.  Right?

Comment: yes exactly i am looking for that

Comment: Do you want to create it from scratch using a machine learning framework or you need an API?

Comment: i want using machine learning framework

Answer (score 1):

**seq2seq RNN models:**

Basically, we need to transform the script of the text from Hindi to English. We can do this with the help of seq2seq RNN models. These models are widely used in Neural Machine Translation. Know more from [here](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html).

> seq2seq RNN models can take the sequence of Hindi words as input and output their corresponding English words.

Note: As these models have done their best in translation between languages, I assume that they can transcript between languages in a pretty well manner.

[image: Neural Machine Translation system]

The above shows how a seq2seq model is used for language translation. Such a model can be used for transcription as well. See this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11os3isH4I4X76dwOAQJ5cSRnfhmUziHm#forceEdit=true&offline=true&sandboxMode=true) for creating such a system in TensorFlow Keras. Refer to these links for more:

1. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-implement-seq2seq-lstm-model-in-keras-shortcutnlp-6f355f3e5639
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/seq2seq-model-in-machine-learning/
3. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/essentials-of-deep-learning-sequence-to-sequence-modelling-with-attention-part-i/

**Limitations:**

- You can get training data for translation easily. But, there is no data available for transcription between Hindi and English.
- For the data, you can try posting a question on [OpenData](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange.

**Tip:**

There's a Google Cloud API for transcription. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/transcription) for more details.